# How to use a bash variable to hold the format of find's printf statement

Tags: bash, variables, format, find, printf

How can `bash` use a variable for the format of `find`'s `-printf` statement?  I am trying to convert the following:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "File: %p has modification time [%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %TZ]\n"
```

which prints the following:

```
File: ./file_20180926_220000.txt has modification time [2018-09-26 22:00:00.0000000000 CDT]
File: ./file_20180926_210000.txt has modification time [2018-09-26 21:00:00.0000000000 CDT]
File: ./file_20180926_230000.txt has modification time [2018-09-26 23:00:00.0000000000 CDT]
```

I want the printf statement to be held in a variable instead, like the following illustrates (but fails).

```
operation="-printf \"File: %p has modification time [%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %TZ]\n\""
find ./ -type f $operation
```

The output of that is:

```
find: paths must precede expression: %p
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
```

Simpler printf formats work, like if I just use `operation="-printf %p"`, but as soon as I use spaces in the format, I get the error above.  I also tried to escape the spaces with `\`, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I would like to avoid `eval` if possible, unless someone can suggest how to use it safely in this context.

Note:
The following works, but requires two variables, while I would prefer to keep just one:

```
operation="-printf"
format="File: %p has modification time [%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %TZ]\n"
find ./ -type f $operation "$format"
File: ./file_20180926_220000.txt has modification time [2018-09-26 22:00:00.0000000000 CDT]
File: ./file_20180926_210000.txt has modification time [2018-09-26 21:00:00.0000000000 CDT]
File: ./file_20180926_230000.txt has modification time [2018-09-26 23:00:00.0000000000 CDT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a single argument in a regular variable:

```
print_format="File: %p has modification time [%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %TZ]\n"
find ./ -type f -printf "$print_format"
```

or you can store one or more arguments in an array:

```
find_options=( -printf "File: %p has modification time [%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %TZ]\n" )
find ./ -type f "${find_options[@]}"
```